# Iterations in Postgres

Tags: postgresql

I've prepared two execute statements in `PostgreSQL` which are both update statements.  I'd like to run two of them as an iterative loop e.g.

```
LOOP
  EXECUTE stage1
  EXECUTE stage2
  IF a = b then EXIT;
  END IF
END LOOP
```

But `PostgreSQL` doesn't like the syntax. Both prepared statements work fine when run on their own, but they take a bit of time and I need to iterate them many times, so I can't really do this manually.  Is there some other way of approaching this?

Comment: How are you running this? It looks like you're trying to use PL/pgSQL; to do that you'll need to use either a DO block or put it in a function.

Comment: Running statements in a loop is very often a very bad sign. In almost all cases it's more efficient to rewrite that into set-based statements that don't do any loops or similar. Why don't you explain us your _real_ problem. Maybe there is a better (more efficient) approach.

Comment: Well, `stage1` and `stage2` are going to be invalid unless you declared them somewhere then set values for them. Perhaps you should show all of the relevant function, and the **exact text of the error message that you get**? Also, what's the underlying problem you're trying to solve? What do `stage1` and `stage2` do, and to what? Are you trying to deal with any concurrency problems (i.e. where multiple connections are doing things to the same tables) here?

Answer (score 0):

Simple sql language does not support such constructs. If you whant to write in PLPGSQL syntax you have to write a function to do that:

```
CREATE FUNCTION some_function() RETURNS void AS $$
--your variable declarations here
BEGIN
        --your code here
END;
$$  LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

you can replace `RETURNS void` with a type you want to return;

read the [documentation here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-createfunction.html)